# To many char read by fread

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

Im am trying to open a file in binary mode and write the content to a buffer in C++.
I am using `fread` for this. However something goes wrong.
My code is:

```
FILE * in = fopen("in", "rb");
_in = new unsigned char [length_in];
fread(_in, sizeof(char), length_in, in);
```

When debugging i can see that `_in = unsigned char *  "Asdfghjkl\x1f \x10"` .

When rebuilding the program, the part `\x1f \x10` changes randomly or disappears.

What i am expecting is always `_in = unsigned char *  "Asdfghjkl"` .

When replacing `length_in` with `9` i still get something like`"Asdfghjkl\x1f \x10"` .

What am I missing. I am using a Mac and Xcode.

Comment: You are reading bytes, not a string.  So the zero-terminator is missing.  Don't ignore the return value of fread() if you want to do it this way.

Comment: Do not ignore the return value of `fread`. It contains vital information, like how much data was actually read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is created uninitialized, so those are garbage values from whatever was in memory beforehand.  Initialize it to zeros like this:

```
_in = new unsigned char [length_in]();
```

Also `fread` returns the number of bytes read. If you’re treating it like a string, make sure the result is null-terminated.